# Sequence with Summation Validation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification

I have the following sequence: $a_n = a_{n-1} - n \space \text{and} \space a_0 = 4$.

**My Solution:**

Doing a "top down" approach:
$$a_{n-1} = (a_{n-2}) - n- n \\ a_{n-2} = (a_{n-3}) - n- n- n \\ \text{factoring out the negative} \\ a_{n-2}= (a_{n-3}) -(n+n+n)\\ \vdots \\ \text{Here is where I question the validity for what I am about to do (it's in the red)}  \\a_k = (a_{n-k}) - \color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^k n} \\ a_k = a_{n-k} - \frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\ \text{Let $k$ = $n$} \\ a_n = (a_{n-n}) - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ a_n = a_0 -\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ \therefore a_n = 4 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$ Obviosuly my question is can I just "slap" the summation here since I know it has the form of something like $1+2+3 + \cdots n$? Or would be "more" correct to show that this sum is growing by the rate I am assuming?

Comment: NOte that :$$a_n = a_{n-1} - n \space \\
n \to n-1 \mapsto a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-(n-1)$$

Comment: Whatever provisional formula you get for $a_n$, you can check it yourself—just see whether it satisfies the initial condition (this one clearly does) and whether it satisfies the recursive equation as well (I believe this one does). As it happens, I think most of your intermediate equations aren't quite correct, but I think you have found your way back to the correct closed formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the wrong track already when you wrote $$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-n-n:$$ the correct version is $a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-(n-1)$. This means that the next two lines are wrong as well.

The first line for $a_k$ has multiple problems: you’re working with a particular $a_n$, meaning with a particular $n$, so you can’t use $n$ as the index of summation. Moreover, this line is inconsistent with the work that preceded it: its lefthand side ought to be $a_{n-k+1}$.

It is possible to get a closed form for this recurrence by ‘unwinding’ it, but you have to get the algebra right:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=a_{n-1}-n\\
&=\big(a_{n-2}-(n-1)\big)-n\\
&=a_{n-2}-(n-1)-n\\
&=\big(a_{n-3}-(n-2)\big)-(n-1)-n\\
&=a_{n-3}-(n-2)-(n-1)-n\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=a_{n-k}-\sum_{i=n-(k-1)}^ni\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=a_{n-n}-\sum_{i=n-(n-1)}^ni\\
&=4-\sum_{i=1}^ni\\
&=4-\frac{n(n+1)}2\,.
\end{align*}$$

And since the step in the middle is actually an extrapolation from the first few lines — an educated guess, if you will — one really should at this point verify that the final expression really does satisfy the recurrence.

This is an easy proof by induction. For $n\ge 0$ let $b_n=4-\frac{n(n+1)}2$; clearly $b_0=4=a_0$. Now suppose that $b_n=a_n$ for some $n\ge 0$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=a_n-(n+1)\\
&=b_n-(n+1)\\
&=4-\frac{n(n+1)}2-(n+1)\\
&=4-\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}2\\
&=b_{n+1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $a_n=b_n=4-\frac{n(n+1)}2$ for all $n\ge 0$.

There are easier ways to get this result. For instance, we can notice that $a_n-a_{n-1}=-n$ for each $n\ge 0$. This means, thanks to telescoping, that

$$\begin{align*}
a_n-a_0&=(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+\ldots(a_1-a_0)\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^nk\\
&=-\frac{n(n+1)}2\,,
\end{align*}$$

and therefore $a_n=a_0-\frac{n(n+1)}2=4-\frac{n(n+1)}2$.

Answer (score 1):

$A_n-A_{n_1}=-n~~~~~(1)$ means the difference is $\Delta A_n=n$. It is like $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=x \implies f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Simlarly. $A_n=an^2+nb+c$, then from (1), we get $$[(an^2+bn+c)-a(n-1)^2+b(n-1)+c]=-n \implies 2an-a-b=-n \implies a=-1/2, b=1/2$$
So $A_n=-n^2/2+n/2+c, A_0=4 \implies c=4$. Finally,  $$A_n=4-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: +1 for such nice solution.

Comment: @Khosrotash Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = a_{n-1} - n  \\ 
a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-(n-1)\\
a_{n-2}=a_{n-3}-(n-2)\\
a_{n-3}=a_{n-4}-(n-3)\\
a_{n-4}=a_{n-5}-(n-4)\\\vdots\\a_2=a_1-2\\a_1=a_0-1$$sum of them
$$a_n = \not a_{n-1} - n  \\ 
\not a_{n-1}=\not a_{n-2}-(n-1)\\
\not a_{n-2}=\not a_{n-3}-(n-2)\\
\not a_{n-3}=\not a_{n-4}-(n-3)\\
\not a_{n-4}=\not a_{n-5}-(n-4)\\\vdots\\
\not a_2=\not a_1-2\\
\not a_1=a_0-1\\a_n=a_0-(1+2+3+4+...+n)$$